# maximum amount of numbers avoiding some of their combinations

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

I have a friend and he presented me this problem: (I dont know if it's his homework or not if that matters, anyway I don't ask for code or something) Algorithmically speaking, how can someone get the maximum of numbers in [1,N] (in efficient time) and at the same time **avoid** their combinations (given the number of combinations, as well as the the quantity of numbers in each combination). for example if we have [1,10] and restrictions (1,10), (9) we would just remove (1 or 10) and 9.

First of all, is it or not a dynamic-programming problem? I am confused.

I would try sorting the combinations in increasing order according to the quantity of numbers they contain and start removing them. In our example, I would first remove 9 (and also all the restrictions that contain 9) etc.

What are your ideas? Let me know if I didn't exmplain something well enough.

Comment: At least to me it's not immediately clear what you intend your restrictions to me. For example, does the `(1, 10)` mean that a combination is prohibited if it contains either 1 or 10, or only if it contains both 1 and 10?

Comment: Yes, it's prohibited to contain in our final list a whole combination of the given.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that last comment didn't clarify much of anything, at least for me.

Comment: We are not allowed to include in our final list numbers that were given as restricted combinations. In our example, we may include 1, 10 but not both of them.

Comment: I'm also not at all clear as to what is being asked.  Perhaps a few more examples would clarify.

Comment: Sounds related to a minimum vertex cover of the hypergraph of restrictions.

Comment: As currently stated, it could be as well related to the halting problem and we wouldn't tell the difference. Please, include more examples of inputs and the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean that for each restriction set, at least one element of the set must be missing from the solution? That doesn't seem to fit with your example, since we wouldn't remove both 1 and 10.

Comment: Ok, let me clear this out. We have a list of numbers. Let's say 1 to 30. We also have a list of prohibited combinations of numbers. i.e. [1 2 3 4 5], [1 2 10], [5]. That means that our desired output must be the maximum list of the initial numbers so that the prohibited combinations are not included. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 must not be included at the same time. same for 1, 2, 10 and same for single number 5.

Comment: Would it be enough to remove 1 in order to avoid the first to restrictions, and 5 to avoid the last? Is there a solution that only removes one number?

Comment: Definitely no. We certainly have to remove 5, and certainly number 1 or number 2 or 10 (us when we remove 5, restriction 1 is not possible anymore. So both [1,2,...30] \{1,5} , [1,2,...,30]\{2,5} and [1,2,...,30]\{5,10} are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard, which means that there probably is no efficient solution.

You can demonstrate NP-hardness by showing that an efficient solution to your problem allows us to efficiently solve a known NP-complete problem like the minimum vertex cover problem.  Here is how we do that.  Take an arbitrary graph.  Turn each edge into a restriction that you don't want both vertices in your set.  Solve your problem.  The complement of the answer you get is a solution to the minimum vertex cover problem.